# Need to remove trailing comma from results

Tags: php, trim

I see previous help for removing trailing commas from strings using rtrim(), but how do I do it in the WHILE section of a query result?

```
<?php 
include '../database_connect.php';

$result=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT filler from a_fillers");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{ 

echo $row['filler'] . ", ";

}

?>
```

The results from the above query are:

Antimicrobic Agent, Molybdenum Disulfide, PTFE, CNT, Glass, Glass, Carbon, Lubricant, Aramide,

I want to remove the last comma after Aramide

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: What abut removing it *after* while loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution is, if you'd like to use rtrim, to build a result string inside the loop and remove the trailing comma after the loop:

```
$result=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT filler from a_fillers");

$output = '';

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{ 
    $output .= $row['filler'] . ", ";
}

echo rtrim( $output, ", " );
```

Comment: Thank you. Worked great! I could not figure out how to create a string within the loop and you taught me that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Check out implode function

```
$result = '';
$items = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{         
    $items[] = $row['filler'];  
}
$result = implode(',', $items);
```

http://php.net/manual/ro/function.implode.php